# Flutter SQFLite How to Save Switch flag selection

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am using Flutter SwitchListTile and SQFLite database to store boolean values as zero and one.

My Goal: I want to save a Switch flag selection in the database.

Issue: When I set the Switch flag on or off, I want to see the corresponding value zero or one (off and on) updated in the database. Currently, the database is showing a default value, and the default value is not updated after I change the flag.

Could you please advise. Thank You

Here is sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() {runApp(MyApp());}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class DataFields {
  static final List<String> values = [id, name, SelectedValue];
  static final String id = '_id'; 
  static final String name = 'myName';
  static final String SelectedValue='isSelected';
}

class DataModel{
  int id;
  String name;
  int isSelected;
  DataModel({required this.id, required this.name, this.isSelected = 0});

  DataModel copy({int? id,String? title,String? description,int? isSelected}) => DataModel(id: id ?? this.id,name: name ?? this.name,isSelected: isSelected ?? this.isSelected);
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {DataFields.id: id,DataFields.name: name,DataFields.SelectedValue: isSelected};
  static DataModel fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => DataModel(id: json[DataFields.id] as int,name: json[DataFields.name] as String,isSelected: json[DataFields.SelectedValue] as int);

}

class DBHelper {
  final String myTable = 'myDataTable';
  static const String myDatabase = 'myDB.db';

  DBHelper._init(); 
  static final DBHelper instance = DBHelper._init();
  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get dataBase async {
    if (_database != null) {return _database!;} else {
      _database = await _initDB(myDatabase);
      return _database!;
    }
  }

  Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);
  }

  Future _createDB(Database db, int version) async {
    var idType = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT';
    var textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';
    await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE $myTable (
    ${DataFields.id} $idType,
    ${DataFields.name} $textType,
    ${DataFields.SelectedValue}
    )''');}

  Future<DataModel> create(DataModel datamodel) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final id = await db.insert(myTable, datamodel.toJson());
    return datamodel.copy(id: id);
  }

  Future<DataModel> readData(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final maps = await db.query(myTable,columns: DataFields.values,where: '${DataFields.id} = ?',whereArgs: [id]);
    if (maps.isNotEmpty) {return DataModel.fromJson(maps.first);} else {throw Exception('ID $id not found');}
  }

  Future<List<DataModel>> readAllData() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $myTable');
    return result.map((json) => DataModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Future<int> countAllDataRows() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    var x = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM $myTable');
    return x.length;
  }

  Future<int> update(DataModel datamodel) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return db.update(myTable,datamodel.toJson(),where: '${DataFields.id} = ?',whereArgs: [datamodel.id]);
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return await db.delete(myTable,where: '${DataFields.id} = ?',whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future close() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    db.close();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<DataModel> names = <DataModel>[];
  TextEditingController mc = TextEditingController();
  int index = 0;

  addItemToList() {setState(() {if (mc.text.isNotEmpty) {
    names.add(DataModel(id:names.length+1, name:mc.text));
    DBHelper.instance.create(DataModel(id:index+1,name:mc.text,isSelected:0));
  }});}

  removeItemFromList(){
    setState(() {
      names.remove(index);
      DBHelper.instance.delete(index);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget space = SizedBox(width: 100, height: 5, child: Text(""));
    Widget myinput = TextField(controller: mc,decoration:InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'));
    Widget btnAdd = ElevatedButton(onPressed: addItemToList, child: Text('Add'));
    Widget btnRemove = ElevatedButton(onPressed: removeItemFromList, child: Text('Remove'));
    Widget mylist = SizedBox(width: 800,height: 500,child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: names.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                SwitchListTile(
                    title: Text(names[index].name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                    value: names[index].isSelected == 1,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      {
                        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                          if (i == index) continue;
                          names[i].isSelected = 0;
                        }
                        names[index].isSelected = value ? 1 : 0;
                        setState(() {
                          mc.text=names[index].name;
                        });
                      };
                    })
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,body: SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: <Widget>[
              Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,children: <Widget>[space,myinput,space,btnAdd,space,btnRemove,space,mylist,space])))]))));
  }
}
```

Comment: cant see your db operation on question

Comment: Hello Yeasin. I updated the code to show DB operations. Please advise how to save Switch flag selection. Thank You

Comment: Hello! Could someone please look into this issue. I really need help on this. Thank You

Comment: [isar](https://isar.dev/) db will be cooler 

Comment: I want to use SQFLite for many reasons. The above code runs, but I need to figure out why the flag is not reflected in the database. If someone will help with this or at least provide a clue, then it would be great! Thank you

Comment: You need read the `readAllData()` to retrive saved item, you can use FutureBuilder for this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly id will be auto generate, you don't need to pass it:

```dart
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        // removed the id, it is auto generated
        DataFields.name: name,
        DataFields.SelectedValue: isSelected,
      };
```

Next is to read database use FutureBuilder, your mylist will be

```dart
    Widget mylist = SizedBox(
      width: 800,
      height: 500,
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: DBHelper.instance
              .readAllData(), // get rebuild on setSate while it is inside build method, better  to create future and dont create widget variable like this,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final data = snapshot.data as List<DataModel>?;

            if (data == null || data.isEmpty) return Text("No Data");

            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SwitchListTile(
                          title: Text(data[index].name,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                          value: data[index].isSelected == 1,
                          onChanged: (bool value) async {
                            {
                              for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                if (i == index) continue;
                                // data[i].isSelected = 0;
                                await DBHelper.instance.update(DataModel(
                                    id: data[i].id,
                                    name: data[i].name,
                                    isSelected: 0));
                              }
                              // names[index].isSelected = value ? 1 : 0;
                              await DBHelper.instance.update(DataModel(
                                  id: data[index].id,
                                  name: data[index].name,
                                  isSelected: value ? 1 : 0));
                              setState(() {});
                            }
                            ;
                          })
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }),
    );
```

---

Lets say you will to remove the last item,

```dart
  removeItemFromList() async {
    await DBHelper.instance.delete(index);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

The dbHelper delete will be

```dart
  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;

    final lastId = await readAllData().then((value) => value.last.id);
    return await db
        .delete(myTable, where: '${DataFields.id} = ?', whereArgs: [lastId]);
  }
```

> The widget structure can be optimized in various ways and needed

Comment: :The wisest structure can be optimized in various ways. My focuse is on db

Comment: Hello Yeasin! Using Future Builder sounds great, but readAllData significantly slows the app performance and I cannot combine future builder with a regular widget. Hence, Add and Remove buttons are no longer working b/c the names list is defined outside of the mylist widget. I cannot put addItemToList and removeItemFromList inside mylist widget. Is there another solution? Could you please help. Thank You